# Config Hotmail with PHPMailer

Tags: php, smtp, localhost, phpmailer, smtpclient

What's the configuration to be able to send emails from my localhost to hotmail using PHPMailer.

```
public static function sendMail($subject, $body, $address) {
        $mail = new PHPMailer();
        $mail->isSMTP();
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
        $mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
        $mail->Host = 'smtp.live.com';
        $mail->Port = 587;
        $mail->isHTML();
        $mail->Username = 'myMail@hotmail.com';
        $mail->Password = 'myMailPass';
        $mail->SetFrom('no-reply@gmail.com');
        $mail->Subject = $subject;
        $mail->Body = $body;
        $mail->AddAddress($address);
        $mail->Send();
```

this is what I have but I can't send emails. It says email was sent, it's in the queue, but it's never delivered.

Comment: I would guess that `setFrom` must be your hotmail address. When you're using SMTP from email services, they usually only allows you to send e-mails from your own address, not from any address.

Comment: It's giving me this output (part of it)
SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 2.6.0 <3180b89a7338cecdebeee84664a25220@127.0.0.1> Queued mail for delivery

Comment: Sure, but have you tried sending from your hotmail address (the same account you're using to login to the SMTP with)? Does that work? Also remember that it can take a while for emails to be sent.

Comment: What do you mean? I'm trying to "create account" and it was supposed to send an email that say something like you've registered! For gmail it works (sort of) but for Hotmail doesn't work at all

Comment: `$mail->SetFrom('no-reply@gmail.com');` Your `from` address is a gmail address and your using live.com (hotmails) SMTP. Try to set `SetFrom` to the same address as you have as `Username` (myMail@hotmail.com). What do you mean by "it works _sort of_ " for gmail?

Comment: I mean, I have to Turn off the less secure apps to be able to receive emails in my GMAIL account